# read selected value from select tag of HTML using javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML code is as:

```
 <div id="detail">
    <div class="d_left">
    Page <strong>1</strong> of 107
    </div>
    <div class="d_center">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Previous</a> | <a href="#">Next</a>
    <img src="/webProject/store/images/arrow.png" align="absmiddle" alt="">
    </td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div class="d_right">
    Sort by:
     <select name="featured" size="1" id="item1">
          <option>Featured Items1</option>
          <option>Featured Items2</option>
          <option>Featured Items3</option>
          <option>Featured Items4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to read selected value from `<select name="featured" size="1" id="item1">`.
How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: When you want to read it? In response to what event?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("item1").value;
```

Comment: James Allardice: You mean there is no need to do like detai1.item1

Comment: @Makram this wont work as the current html doesnot contains value in options.

Comment: @sushil bharwani Actually it will work, because the first option is always selected - http://jsfiddle.net/VUNb3/

Answer (score 5):

More Elegant variant of [sushil bharwani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675125/read-selected-value-from-select-tag-of-html-using-javascript-code/6675161#6675161) solution

```
function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

var select = $("item1");
select.onchange = function() {
    var selIndex = select.selectedIndex;
    var selValue = select.options(selIndex).innerHTML;
}
```

As [Shadow Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard) do not like this solution I hope he will like that:

```
var select = document.getElementById("item1");
select.onchange = function() {
    var selIndex = select.selectedIndex;
    var selValue = select.options(selIndex).innerHTML;
}
```

The main idea in these two example is to reduce the usage of getElementById. No point to execute it more than once - thus [minimizing the access to the DOM](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#dom_access).

For those who feel brave enough :) there is this new thing `querySelector()`<sup>[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector), [msdn IE dev center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)</sup>:

```
var select = document.querySelector("#item1");
```

Comment: Where did you see jQuery? Why you assume it can be used?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard it is pure JavaScript - no jQuery involved here. It is not a selector it is a short for getElementById. The function name can start with a-z A-Z $ _

Comment: Sorry guys I used to work with IE7 for far too long saw now that `options` can be also accessed as a function and the `$` stuff also confused me. Vote undone, will put more time to reading and testing in the future.

Comment: select.options(selIndex) this is not work, select.options[selIndex] this is work

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("item1").onchange = function(){
var selIndex = document.getElementById("item1").selectedIndex;
var selValue = document.getElementById("item1").options[selIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Two errors in one line: `options` is array and `option` element has no innerHTML just value or text.

Comment: OK, now that you fixed the array part (using square brackets) [it's working](http://jsfiddle.net/qaEze/) in all major browsers - innerHTML didn't work for me long time ago guess it was "fixed" in IE7 and above.

Answer (score 2):

```
function delivery(x){
      var country = x.value;
      document.getElementById('lala').innerHTML = country;
}
<div id="lala"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="delivery(this)">
    <option value='lala'>Select Country</option>
    <option value='United_Kingdom'>United Kingdom</option>
    <option value='Russia'>Russia</option>
    <option value='Ukraine'>Ukraine</option>
    <option value='France'>France</option>
    <option value='Spain'>Spain</option>
    <option value='Sweden'>Sweden</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Here is how i solved my problem for selecting eu countries (i have removed most of them to make my codes shorter).. as im new to javascript.. i still need to learn javascript libraries.